# Envio de parametros por url, conflicto con espacios

Tags: java

Estoy realizando una activacion de cuenta de correo por medio de un url donde se envia a un correo electronico, al oprimir el url envia las variables por parametro a un controlador si el usuario no ingresa espacios todo funciona bien pero mi problema es que si ingresan espacios el url se daña en el espacio.
Mi codigo es el siguiente

```
                        // Se envia a correo electronico de un usuario para que realice activacion de la cuenta
                        mail.setSubject("ACTIVACION DE CUENTA.");
                        mail.setText("Ingresa al siguiente link y activa tu cuenta http://localhost:8080/app/validate?accion=activateaccount&nm=" + us.getNombres() + "&ap=" + us.getApellidos() + "&tl=" + us.getTelefono()
                                + "&em=" + us.getCorreo() + "&ar=" + us.getArea() + "&rl=" + us.getRol());
```

Comment: Prueba con esto: ```
System.out.println(aux.replace(" ","%20"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba eliminando los espacios en blanco en el correo, antes que hagas el `mail.setText()`.

Algo como esto:

```
System.out.println(us.getCorreo().replace(" ",""));
```

La funcion `replace` eliminara todos los espacios.

No te recomiendo la funcion `trim()` porque solo funciona para detectar espacios al inicio y al final de la cadena, por lo que si en tu correo colocan un espacio al medio, este siempre fallará.

Para separar el nombre y apellido, tienes la opcion de separar cuando haya una letra mayúscula de por medio, mira este ejemplo:

```
String a = "AngelaLorena";
System.out.println(a.replaceAll("\\d+", "").replaceAll("(.)([A-Z])", "$1 $2"));
```

Puedes aplicar esto para guardar esta información separada o tambien al momento que la quieras mostrar la puedes separar.

Comment: OK si funciono muchas gracias pero en la base de datos se registran los nombres y apellidos pegados si hago esto al registrar en la db se eliminan los espacios ``` .replace("", " ") ``` solo a los que les quite el espacio en el envio del url ??? sirve ??

Comment: Si, en este caso solo le estas quitando los espacios a us.getCorreo(), nombres y apellidos seguirán normal.

Comment: Ya probe lo que dije el orimer caso funciono para no dañar el url pero ya cuando registra el usuario intente volver a despegar los dos nombres uno del otro pero entobnces queda asi = A n g e l i t a de esta manera: 

`   ssnewuser.setAttribute("NOMBRES", request.getParameter("nm").replace("", " "));`

Comment: Lo que necesitas ahora es guardar nombre y apellido separados?

Comment: Bardales Si exacto al enviar el url necesito que todo este pegado pero ya al oprimir el url paso parametros y los guardo en session para que al activar la cuenta se envien esos parametros del url a la base de datos y que llege nombre 1 aparte de nomnre 2 (Angela Lorena) si dejo todo como en el url en la DB quedaria AngelaLorena y tengo una lista en la vista del programa donde muestra los usuarios y no seria adecuado mostrar dos nombres pegados

Comment: He modificado la respuesta, ahi esta el codigo para separar el nombre. Espero sea de tu ayuda.

Comment: Oye funciono super muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Para casos como esos, donde te interesa eliminar los elementos al principio y al final de los cuadros de texto existe la funcion `trim()` . Esta, elimina los todos los espacios al inicio y al final del String.

Otra opcion, menos utilizada, pero util en este caso es lo que te dice el anterior comentario: `replace(" ","")`, pero aqui eliminarias **todos** los espacios.